# how to get the reference for the control in dragdrop event?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 1 list of picturebox (source picturebox A), they are generated dynamically in the code. I have another list of picturebox (destination picture box B, dynamically generated too). Now, I can drag drop images from any of A to any of B, vice versa.

Now, I want to add this feature: when drag drop image from B to any of the A, reset the image in that picturebox in B (but keep other images in other picturebox in B) . In the A's drag drop event, I'm doing

```
private void picA_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap)))
        {
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            pb.Image = (Bitmap)(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap));                
        }
    }
```

It is for set the image from B to A. Now, how can I reset the image in B?

thanks

reader

Answer (score 0):

You can, for example, process `DragLeave` event on the `B`, for example store it's reference in some `dragSource` class variable. Then set `dragSource.Image` in `picA_DragDrop`.